# How to set font color on User Input file field of IzPack?

Tags: java, izpack

How could I set the color in the follow field message? The text "Please enter the Jboss directory name." should appear in red.

```
<field type="staticText" align="left" txt="Please enter the Jboss directory name."  conditionid="con_jboss_installed"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the sources, the description field supports HTML rendering (it is looking for  and  at the beginning and end of the text), so the following is supposed to work:

```
<field type="staticText" align="left" conditionid="con_jboss_installed">
  <description><html><body><p style="color: red;">Please enter the Jboss directory name.</p></body></html></description>
</field>
```

This would require IzPack 5.